# Should I apply for a 1 year eVisa or for a 30day one?

Tags: visas, india, italian-citizens

I am an Italian citizen and I booked a planned trip to India.
To reduce time and risks I chose to not use the agency but apply for an eVisa myself.

I was looking and the official site and I have seen that I can apply for both a short 30day eTourist Visa and a longer 1 year eTourist one. I have never applied for a Visa (Thanks Schengen!), and now I'm not sure what's the best choice.

- With a longer visa, I have more time if for any reason I have to postpone the trip, and even if I don't, I still have the occasion to go back (but who got the money for that.) If not anything else, I got more than 2 entries, which could be useful.
- With the shorter Visa, I only got two entries, but it starts from the day of my arrival, and I guess it should be easier to obtain?
- I have found no indication that the fee is different, which sounds strange to me but not too much.

Any suggestion? What is your suggestion? The trip is planned for the first two weeks of March and I don't see any foreseeable reason I will not be able to attend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the past, and as I read, 1 year visa is more difficult to obtain the first time. You may get few short term visa, and then you can ask a long term visa. If you have good reasons, you can apply also the first time for a long term visa.

If I remember correctly the short term visa is valid for 3 months (you have 3 mouths for the first entry), so it should be enough if there are delays.  From consular person (not for India), it seems that having non-used visa is always seen as positive fact (for further visas).

Personally, I would not think too much about getting a long term visa, but I would try to apply as early as possible. The website is not the most userfriendly, and fields are not well designed (you probably will fill the "countries you visited last 10 years: as European it is easier to get enough countries to fill all the space), you will get a visa confirmation on email, but it is not the visa [which is hidden on their website]. And the different format requirements of photo of passport and of your face? Good luck also for the payment system. You have time, but do not wait too much.